# Hyperbolic space is complete

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I am trying to prove the hyperbolic space is complete. It looks one need to apply Hopf-Rinow theorem, but I don't know what to start. More precisely, I don't know what is a good way to show the exponential map is defined on the entire $T_{p}M$.

Another approach probably be proving that with the hyperboloid model $x_{0}^{2}-x_{1}^{2} \cdots -x_{n}^{2}=1$ is a complete metric space under the distance $d(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=arcosh (x_{0}y_{0}-x_{1}y_{1}-\cdots-x_{n}y_{n})$.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean topologicaly complete or geodesicaly complete. I don't really now hyperbolic geometry. But on the wikipedia page, it is said that the hyperbolic space $H^n$ is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. So it is topologicaly complete.

Comment: I mean geodesically complete.

Comment: It seems that Hopf-Rinow theorem says that topologicaly complete and geodesically complete are equivalent.

Comment: Why completeness is preserved under diffeomorphism?

Comment: You're right, I'm just silly !